# JSON LD Format Blogposting with keywords

Tags: blogger, schema.org, json-ld

I have found that I can use the JSON-LD format BlogPosting with Keywords. Is there a way to automatically use the keywords in JSON-LD when they are defined like that `<meta content='put all your keywords here separated by comma' name='keywords'/>` in the single blogposts in blogspot? Is there a way to "call" them like `"description": "<data:view.description.escaped/>"` or `"keywords": "<data:post.labels/>",` to show the meta description of a single post?

Comment: try https://schema.org/keywords on https://schema.org/CreativeWork. for multiple keywords, use an array. Make sure you do not use keywords that, at a minimum, are not synonyms for concepts and terms in the target https://schema.org/Blog. you will suffer if you use keywords unrelated to content.

Answer (score 0):

**No you can't.**

There's no way to get post object components outside widget, you can get it simply within Blog widget using `<data:post.labels/>` array:

```xml
&lt;meta name='keywords' content='<b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'><data:label.name/>,</b:loop>'/&gt;
```

**BUT** meta tags in `<body>` **[is invalid as per HTML4.01](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#h-7.4.4)**, it should be within `<head>` tag.

On the other hand, **[meta Keywords is not supported by google anymore since 2009](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html)**, you don't need to use it just include post tags within post search description in a balanced way.

Although there are some other ways to tell search engines about your tags or nested pages, like **[Schema.org/Breadcrumbs](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumb)** and **[hAtom](http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-tag)**.